# Location of std::to_string function

Tags: c++

What is the reason std::to_string function is not a method of std::string class ? Because it would be logically more appropriate, isn't it? I want to know why they would not make it:

1. a static member function of std::string class
2. why would they not integrate it with constructor, so it would be possible to do like std::string ten( 10 ) and to get "10"?

Comment: Implicit conversion of arguments are dangerous and it will have unpredicted behaviors  which are hard to debug.

Comment: ad 1) What would be gained by doing so? Would you prefer writing `std::string::to_string()` instead of `std::to_string`? ad 2) So you think, `std::string` should provide a constructor taking an `int`? How about `float`, `double` or `unsigned` or `std::size_t`, `std::uint32_t`, `std::int64_t`, `std::pair<int, int>`? `std::pair<int, char>`? How many constructors should there be? What about user defined types?

Comment: By making it a freestanding function, it enables you to define your own overloads.

Comment: I think you mean to ask "Why is `to_string()` not a member of `int` and other types, so you can do something like `int foo = 42; string bar = foo.to_string();`. The reason is that not everything is an object, as Yakk points out in his answer. In other languages, like C#, this is possible because *everything* is an object, and the base object of everything has a `ToString()` method, which everything else then inherits (there are other mechanisms as well).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel That would be a valid reason if the standard allowed it but it actually says it's undefined behaviour to overload `std::to_string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is not a OO language.  You can write OO code in C++, but you can also not.

`to_string` is not written in an OO style.

There are advantages; the largest one is your code can choose to treat `to_string` as a customization point by doing

```
using std::to_string;
std::string foo=to_string(x);
```

and now any type that implements a `to_string` in its enclosing namespace works with the above code.

Also, `to_string` is arguably a method of both source and destination APIs; being a method of either is thus questionable.